# Django UserCreationForm Customization

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am fairly new to django and creating a website that involves account creation. The standard form UserCreationForm is fairly ugly. My main issue with it is that it displays a list of information under the password field. It displays the code in html as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>Your password can’t be too similar to your other personal information.</li>
    <li>Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li>
    <li>Your password can’t be a commonly used password..</li>
    <li>Your password can’t be entirely numeric</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to change how this is being displayed? I want to maybe delete one or two of the fields or change how it looks. Can I change some information in my custom form maybe? My forms.py for this specific form is as follows:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2' )
```

I am unsure how to change this because it isn't an errorlist or anything like that. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to more googling I have found the answer needed! You can override the **init** method to change or get rid of them entirely like so:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].label = 'Password'
        self.fields['password2'].label = 'Password Confirmation'
        self.fields['first_name'].label = 'First Name'
        self.fields['last_name'].label = 'Last Name'

        self.fields['password1'].help_text = None
        self.fields['password2'].help_text = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2' )
        help_texts = {
            'username': None,
        }
```

if you notice the help_texts dictionary in the meta class this method seems to only work for username helptext and not for the passwords for some reason unknown to me

Answer (score 0):

You can render the form manually field by field, so this information won't be rendered in your template. Like so

```html
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.first_name.label_tag }}
    {{ form.first_name }}
</div>

<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.last_name.label_tag }}
    {{ form.last_name }}
</div>

... other fields ...
```

It also allows you to further customize design of your forms.

Link: [Django docs | Rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Comment: I am doing this in a way with a for loop, I phrased my question wrong in my original question. I would more so like to change the actual helptext itself, but since I am using Django to create the form for me I am not sure if this is possible haha. I could leave out field.help_text in my form but I want to avoid that :)

Comment: You can redefine the default password field on the form. 

`password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password")`